# What is the meaning of & in button Name parameter?

Tags: python, wxpython

When I create a button in `wxpython` I can do:

```
self.all = wx.Button(self, -1, _("&ALL"))
```

or

```
self.all = wx.Button(self, -1, _("ALL"))
```

both generate a button named `ALL`

So, what is the meaning of the `&` in the name parameter?

[ducomntation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Button-class.html#__init__) doesn't specify anything about it.

the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726544/creating-menus-using-wxpython) is similar but it's not the same. The solution there is set focus. while you can set focus to a menu, you can not set focus to a button.

Comment: It looks like the `&` goes before the keyboard shortcut character.

Comment: Have you ever noticed that dialog boxes often have one of the letters of the button labels underlined? That means you can type that letter instead of clicking on the button.

Comment: So `&ALL` will show something like `_A_ll` and you can click on the button by typing `A`.

Comment: Show where? In both cases the button text i see in the screen is `ALL`.

Comment: it's not duplicated. You can't set focus on button... it might be similar but it's not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `&` indicates the keyboard shortcut that can be used to activate the button. So `&All` means you can press <kbd>A</kbd> instead of clicking on the `All` button.

You can put the `&` anywhere in the label, the character after it becomes the shortcut. For instance, one of the stock labels on the documentation page is:

```
wx.ID_CUT   'Cu&t'
```

This means that <kbd>T</kbd> is the shortcut for the *Cut* button.

Comment: Can you elaborate how do I use the shourtcut? pressing  `A ` does nothing.  and what if I have `self.all = wx.Button(self, -1, _("&ALL")) self.all2 = wx.Button(self, -1, _("&ALL2"))`   . How does python know which shourtcut i ment?

Comment: You shouldn't give the same shortcut to multiple buttons in the same dialog. I don't know how it deals with it, probably just assigns it to the first or last button.

Comment: It might also require a modifier key, like Alt-A.

Comment: Ok. but even if I have only 1 button. The shourtcut doesn't work. not by clicking `A` `ALT+A` `CTRL+A`. nothing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049406/wxpython-button-shortcut-accelerator-how-to-spam, it mentions a GTK configuration setting `gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1` that's needed.

Comment: I rechecked my software The alt+key works on menus.. but it doesn't work on buttons... could there be any other reason? if gtk-auto-mnemonics  was 0 it shouldn't have work at all.

Comment: Sorry, this is way out of my area of expertise. I've never used GTK or wxpython myself, I'm just going from what I figured out by googling.

Answer (score 0):

I guess (keyword: GUESS) is since you are building a GUI, you may want to consider internationalisation [link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization). This is done by searching through your `*.py` file and search for any string that could be replaced to a different language, using UNICODE. By having `&` in front of the string displaying your button, you can easily search for it using, maybe, `gettext`.

Again, a guessing answer :)